# generics and static

Tags: java, generics, static-methods

In this book that I'm using to brush up, there's a relationship between generic methods and the static keyword. It appears that generic methods require that keyword, but I don't see why it's required?

Here's what the book did:

```
 static <T> void myFunction(T [] myArray) {
     //......
 }
```

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - Yea.  You have misunderstood the book.  That example does not mean that you *have to* use `static` with generic methods.

Answer (score 8):

There is no requirement that generic methods be static. See [Section 8.4.4 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4) for details (including links to other relevant parts of the spec). At the same time, there's nothing wrong with a generic method being `static` (or vice versa), either. It all depends on the design requirements.

Comment: Thank you Ted. Could you please help me understand why you'd want to make it static vs not?

Comment: @nivyaj - I usually make a method static when all of the following conditions hold: (1) the method does not override a superclass instance method (this is a technical requirement); (2) the method makes no use of instance data of its class; (3) the method does not need to maintain state data internally (this is basically a duplicate of (2)); (4) there cannot be a reason to override this method in a subclass. The last is actually a quite common reason to _not_ make a method static--e.g., when applying the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).